# Serving Images using Tornado without File I/O

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, webcam, tornado

I'm trying to serve a webcam image using Tornado library but the only way I found is to save the image first and then return the image name.

Is there a way to serve the image without saving to disk?

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image
from time import time
from io import StringIO

pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
cam.start()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):


        img = cam.get_image()
        name = str( round( time() ) )
        name = name + '.jpg'
        pygame.image.save(img, name)


        self.write('<img src="' + name + '">')



application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r'/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': ''})
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like pygame supports saving an image to a file-like object, so you won't be able to use it directly. However, it does have a [`tostring`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.tostring) method. The documentation for that notes that it allows interopability with other image libraries:

> Creates a string that can be transferred with the ‘fromstring’ method
>   in other Python imaging packages

So, you can use `tostring` to turn your image into a string, then use another Python library which supports writing an image to a file-like object, and use its `fromstring` method,

Here's an example using [`pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) as the alternative image library.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from PIL import Image
import cStringIO as StringIO

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("<img src='http://localhost:8888/img'>")

class ImgHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    img_name = "bg.jpg"
    img = pygame.image.load(img_name)
    str_img = pygame.image.tostring(img, "RGB")
    size = img.get_size()
    fimg = Image.frombytes("RGB", size, str_img, "raw")
    fobj = StringIO.StringIO()
    fimg.save(fobj, format="png")  #jpeg encoder isn't available in my install...
    for line in fobj.getvalue():
        self.write(line)
    self.set_header("Content-type",  "image/png")


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/img", ImgHandler),
    #(r'/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': ''})
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Both `localhost:8888` and `localhost:8888/img` will display the image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can serve images without dealing with `File I/O`. I have a `python3` [application](https://github.com/TamerTas/Solomon/) that tracks the users by sending a 1x1 pixel using `Tornado`

I store the image as such in the [source code](https://github.com/TamerTas/Solomon/blob/master/solomon.py#L68):

```
# 1x1 Transparent Pixel in HEX Format
pixel_GIF = [0x47,0x49,0x46,0x38,0x39,0x61,
             0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x80,0x00,
             0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,
             0xff,0x21,0xf9,0x04,0x01,0x00,
             0x00,0x00,0x00,0x2c,0x00,0x00,
             0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00, 
             0x00,0x02,0x01,0x44,0x00,0x3b]
```

Then, I convert the image in `HEX` format to binary by using the following [function](https://github.com/TamerTas/Solomon/blob/master/solomon.py#L135):

```
def pack_into_binary(data):
    """Convert given data into binary form"""
    packed = str()
    for datum in data:
        packed += struct.pack('B', datum).decode("ISO-8859-1")
    return packed

pixel_binary = pack_into_binary(pixel_GIF)
```

After that I [set the headers](https://github.com/TamerTas/Solomon/blob/master/solomon.py#L248) appropriately and [serve the image](https://github.com/TamerTas/Solomon/blob/master/solomon.py#L260):

```
#1x1 Transparent Tracking Pixel
self.set_header("Content-Length", 42)
self.set_header("Content-Type", "image/gif")
self.set_header("Pragma", "no-cache")
self.set_header("Cache-Control", 
                "no-store, "
                "no-cache=Set-Cookie, "
                "proxy-revalidate, "
                "max-age=0, "
                "post-check=0, pre-check=0"
                )
self.set_header("Expires", "Wed, 2 Dec 1837 21:00:12 GMT")
self.write(self.pixel_binary)
```

Without doing any `File I/O`.

**Note:** In your case if you have the image in memory you can serve it by converting the format to binary and using `write` method. The difference is your image is not pre-determined unlike mine.

**Edit:** Check below for the example conversion from `RGB Surface` to `binary` encoding

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

data = pygame.image.tostring(cam.get_image(),"RGB")

img = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (100,200), data) # 100 x 200 example surface
zdata = StringIO()

img.save(zdata, 'JPEG')

self.write(zdata.getvalue())
```

Then you can serve `image` using `Tornado`

Comment: How should the OP get the `pygame` image into the correct HEX format?

Comment: @dano any format will suffice I just showed him an example of `Tornado` serving images without using `File I/O`. Your downvote is uncalled for.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the OP can make use of this answer, since all he's got is a `pygame.Surface` object to work with. The missing piece for him is how to get that into a format that he can display via a web page, without writing it to disk (writing it to disk means pygame will convert it to a usable format).

Comment: Added an example conversion snippet

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but how do you get the base64-encoded, RGB 24-bit string to actually display via tornado as an image? Is there a `Content-type` I don't know about?

Comment: @dano agreed `base64` was an off choice. But after using `tostring` it's really a matter of `str_to_binary` conversion.

Comment: Right, but what I was trying to get at is that you need a second imaging library to do that conversion (as far as I know). Which is exactly what my answer (and now, the edited-in part of your answer) says.

Comment: @dano At first I was focused on the `Tornado` part but, not the conversion part. Now I see that it was a two-fold question.

Answer (score -1):

Sure! Something like:

```
class ImageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        img = cam.get_image()
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
        self.write(img.contents)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/image.jpg", ImageHandler),
])
```

I don't know exactly how to get the image's contents as bytes, but you get the idea.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible, because `img` isn't stored in-memory in jpg format. It converts it to some internal format that `pygame` uses.